# Why width is set different on input elements

Tags: html, css, width, quirks-mode

I am banging my head for quite a long time and don't what's going wrong with setting width of input elements.

[Here 100px set width for submit button](http://jsfiddle.net/gn3Cw/)
[Here same 100px is set to text field](http://jsfiddle.net/gn3Cw/1/)

And you can check the difference of width. It seems one is following quirks mode BUT WHY when same doctype is set?

Is it a bug in FX/Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because of the border size
try this,

http://jsfiddle.net/gn3Cw/2/

http://jsfiddle.net/gn3Cw/3/

Comment: Yes, if in Chrome inspect the elements. Then expand the 'metrics' section on right side. You will see that one of them is 96px with 2px left/right borders whereas the other is 100px with 2px left/right borders.

Comment: I understand it but I tried to find default borders [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) and no info founds. Its weird :|

Answer (score 2):

by adding a `box-sizing:border-box` to input text will solve it.

because the default calculate width and height without the border included , by adding  `box-sizing:border-box` The sum of width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin will be 100px

http://jsfiddle.net/wizztjh/gn3Cw/6/

more information of [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing)

Answer (score 1):

Text fields have built in borders. Look what happens when you remove borders : [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/gn3Cw/5/)

Comment: I understand it but I tried to find default borders [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) and no info founds. Its weird :|